# Rewrite base url based on domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, yii

I'm doing a website with Yii, which consists of different modules that should be accessed from different top level domains. I need, because of that, that every base depends on the module. Plus, the country code should also be checked and sent as a get parameter. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187117/how-to-rewrite-url-based-on-domain-in-apache-and-add-extra-parameter):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.micrositedomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://bigsite.com/microsite/$1?lang=en [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.micrositedomain\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://bigsite.com/microsite/$1?lang=es [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.micrositedomain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://bigsite.com/microsite2/$1?lang=en [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.micrositedomain2\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://bigsite.com/microsite2/$1?lang=es [QSA]
```

However, I'm not pretty sure where to handle this. It should obviously be in an .htaccess in the root, but I don't know how to mix it with my .htaccess already there:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Also, I'm pretty sure that my hosting administrators should point each domain (www.micrositedomain.com, www.micrositedomain2.com...) to bigsite.com root, not each module, but I can't really assure that.

Which step by step should I follow to accomplish that?

## tl;dr

For those in a hurry, I want to:

- **Rewrite urls from different domains/country codes to a single domain, and pass those parameters.**
- **Tell my hosting administrator where the domains should point to.**

How would you solve this in my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to make it in .htaccess, but you could make it in yii config. Try something like this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'http://<module:\w+>\.<domain:(micrositedomain|microdomain2)>\.<zone:(com|es)>/<controller>/<action>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

After that you should put some MyController.php in components folder

```
class MYController extends CController
{
    public $domain='micrositedomain';
    public $language='en';

    public function init() {
        if(isset($_GET['zone']))
        {
            $this->language=($_GET['zone']=='com')?'en':$_GET['zone'];
        }
        if(isset($_GET['domain']))
        {
            $this->domain=$_GET['domain'];
        }
    }
}
```

All your controllers should extend this.

All your domains should point to directory with your application

Comment: Better late than ever. After fighting for about two months with the hosting provider (which claimed to be great at htaccess), they just couldn't do what you achieved in just a few lines. If I could +2 you, I would!